# Another simple ASP.NET MVC2 Question - ViewModels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

This is the ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using AfvClassifieds.Models;

namespace AfvClassifieds.ViewModels
{
    public class ClassifiedsIndexViewModel
    {
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Let me explain this one, I want to capture everything from my Category table. I then want to pass it to my view using a "strongly typed view". This I populate my new ViewModel:

```
 // Retrieve the categories table from the database.
            var categoryModel = AfvClassifiedsDB.Categories.ToList();

            // Set up our ViewModel
            var viewModel = new ClassifiedsIndexViewModel()
            {
                Categories = categoryModel,
            };
```

Then I want to iterate through my table in the view: **(This is were its gone wrong).**

```
<% 
        foreach (string categoryName in Model.Categories)
        {
        %>
```

I think you could summarise my problem as an issue of iterating through a list in C#?

The error is as follows:

> Cannot convert type 'AfvClassifieds.Models.Category' to 'string'

Comment: What has gone wrong? I don't understand anything from your question. What issue iterating? What are you trying to do? That doesn't look like a view model at all if you are going to dump your database in it.

Comment: What string exactly. Stop using vars in code examples. We're no compilers.

Comment: @the_drow, what exactly is your problem with `var`? Can't you look 5 pixels right from the assignment operator to know the type? I think `var` is one of the greatest additions to the C# language as it makes it much more concise. So in the OPs case we have a `ToList()` extension method which more than obviously returns a `List<Category>` and as far as the `ClassifiedsIndexViewModel` type is concerned, I think it doesn't deserve any comment. You might say that in the case of `List<Category>` you don't know how the `Category` class looks like but even without `var` you wouldn't know it...

Comment: ... As a side note if he hadn't used `var` there would have been a horizontal scrollbar in the code snippets which would have made things even worse :-)

Comment: This is a generally bad idea to use var in code examples. I can understand why it's useful but it makes the code less clear about your intentions. In real code it's appropriate whenever you have very long type names (in c++ to get an iterator you'll have to type std::list<T>::iterator instead of typing auto).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so instead of:

```
foreach (string categoryName in Model.Categories)
```

do:

```
<% foreach (var category in Model.Categories) { %>
    <div><%: category.Name %></div>
<% } %>
```

or:

```
<% foreach (Category category in Model.Categories) { %>
    <div><%: category.Name %></div>
<% } %>
```

or even better: use display templates and never write a single `foreach` in your view:

```
<%: Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Categories) %>
```

and in `~/Views/YourControllerName/DisplayTemplates/Category.ascx`:

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AfvClassifieds.Models.Category>" %>
<div><%: Model.Name %></div>
```

Comment: @JHarley1, next time include the error message you are getting. It makes things clear at first sight. Also don't forget the green tick if this answer was helpful to you.

Comment: Cheers Darin. The answer was v.helpful. I had to wait for a period of time before I could mark the answer as correct.